# Delete all files except 3 files VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, delete-file, except

I have this code

```
 Private Sub DeleteOldFiles(
        ByVal AsDirectoryName As String,
        ByVal AbDeleteSubDirectories As Boolean,
        ByVal AbDeleteFolders As Boolean)

        If AbDeleteSubDirectories Then
            Dim m_sSubdirectoryName As String

            For Each m_sSubdirectoryName In
            System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(AsDirectoryName)
                DeleteOldFiles _
                    (m_sSubdirectoryName,
                    AbDeleteSubDirectories,
                    AbDeleteFolders)

                If AbDeleteFolders Then
                    System.IO.Directory.Delete(m_sSubdirectoryName)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        Dim m_sFileName As String

        For Each m_sFileName In
        System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(AsDirectoryName)
            If m_sFileName <> "p2ptv_preview01.zip" Then
                System.IO.File.Delete(m_sFileName)
            End If
        Next
```

and DeleteOldFiles("./", True, True) on a button control. 
but, this code works only with one file.
i want to except more files.
how can I do this?

Comment: It is only deleting one file and the other files are not `"p2ptv_preview01.zip"`?  Just for experimentation, what happens when you run this code with a path of something temporary like `DeleteOldFiles("c:\temp", True, True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in a list of exempt files you don't want to delete and see if the current filename is in that list.

```
Private Sub DeleteOldFiles(
    ByVal AsDirectoryName As String,
    ByVal AbDeleteSubDirectories As Boolean,
    ByVal AbDeleteFolders As Boolean,
    ByVal exemptFileNames As IEnumerable(Of String))

    If AbDeleteSubDirectories Then
        Dim m_sSubdirectoryName As String

        For Each m_sSubdirectoryName In
        System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(AsDirectoryName)
            DeleteOldFiles _
                (m_sSubdirectoryName,
                AbDeleteSubDirectories,
                AbDeleteFolders,
                exemptFileNames)

            If AbDeleteFolders Then
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(m_sSubdirectoryName)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Dim m_sFileName As String

    For Each m_sFileName In
    System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(AsDirectoryName)
        If exemptFileNames.Contains(m_sFileName) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Skipped " & m_sFileName)
        Else
            System.IO.File.Delete(m_sFileName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim exemptFilenames As New List(Of String)()
    exemptFilenames.Add("p2ptv_preview01.zip")
    exemptFilenames.Add("name2.txt")
    exemptFilenames.Add("name3.tar")
    DeleteOldFiles("./", True, True, exemptFilenames)
End Sub
```